# How to add a Label to a ProgressTimer's Sprite in Cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to get a `ProgressTimer` to work with a `Sprite` that's got a `Label` as a child. It seems like only the `Sprite` and none of its children are being used as the sprite for the progress bar.

I've got the label created, added it to the sprite. I added the sprite to both the `ProgressTimer` and scene, because I wanted to make sure that it should look good. Removing the label from the scene and giving it only to the `ProgressTimer` doesn't seem to do anything different.

Then I create the `ProgressTimer` using the `Sprite`, configure it and then add it to my scene.

I've briefly looked into using RenderTexture to create a texture and pass that into a Sprite and work from there, but didn't get anywhere past seeing a blurrier upside down `mysprite.png`.

How can I get the `Label` in the `Sprite` to show up on the `ProgressTimer` in my scene?

```
//init label
Label* lbl = Label::createWithTTF("My label", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);
lbl->setTextColor(Color4B::RED);

//init sprite
Sprite* sprite = Sprite::create("mysprite.png");
sprite->addChild(lbl);

scene->addChild(sprite); //make sure it works normally

auto progress_timer = ProgressTimer::create(sprite);

progress_timer->setScale(1.5);
progress_timer->setPercentage(100);

scene->addChild(progress_timer);
```

Comment: Looking through the cocos source, it looks like the progress timer takes the texture right from the sprite. Must need to create a texture manually then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SteveTranby's solution, I found one that worked for me. The problem with setting AutoDraw is that I believe it expects the scheduled update to run, so it doesn't actually render anything, unless you call `render` on the director's Renderer, so I resorted to manually drawing to the sprite.

I also had an issue with distortion, so I disabled antialiasing and made sure I wasn't doing any scaling at all. I set the anchor to 1,1 because the default of 0,0 cut off half the image, and then I also had to flip the image around. I'm not sure why.

```
//sprite for base layer
auto prog_sprite = Sprite::create("progbar.png");
auto fmt = prog_sprite->getTexture()->getPixelFormat();
auto size = prog_sprite->getContentSize();

auto lbl = Label::createWithTTF("label text", "fontpath, size.height);
lbl->setTextColor(Color4B::RED);

//sprite for label
auto lbl_sprt = Sprite::create();
lbl_sprt->addChild(lbl);
rt = RenderTexture::create(size.width, size.height, fmt);

rt->begin();
//draw base sprite to texture
prog_sprite->getTexture()->setAliasTexParameters();
prog_sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(1, 1));
prog_sprite->setPosition(size.width, size.height);
prog_sprite->visit();

//draw label sprite to texture
lbl_sprt->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(1, 1));
lbl_sprt->setPosition(10, 10);
lbl_sprt->visit();
rt->end();

//create a sprite from the new texture
Texture2D* text2d = rt->getSprite()->getTexture();
text2d->setAliasTexParameters();
auto final_sprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(text2d);
final_sprite->setFlippedY(true);

//create the final progresstimer
this->prog_timer = ProgressTimer::create(final_sprite);
```

Most methods on the sprites before the texture, such as anchor point and flipping it, don't seem to matter. Position does.

Note that if you `setSprite` on the ProgressTimer after you've called setPercentage once already, you'll need to set it to another value, and then back again, so that the internal sprite/texture gets updated. I think this is a bug, so beware.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use ProgressTimer as it exists and either embed your label at build time (as part of asset resources) or using a RenderTexture if you want to change the label on the fly.

I've seen some games have the label and progress background always visible and just have the bar itself fill up. Usually when it's a health bar or loading, so you may want to look at adding a background so the label doesn't look weird alone while the progress fills up.

You could also look at building out your own sprite+label progress timer using ClippingNode or custom commands. Labels are fundamentally a set of sprites inside a spritebatch. This would be a bit of work though.

To use RenderTexture, something like this:

```
Size size = sprite->getContentSize();

auto rt = RenderTexture::create(size.width, size.height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);
rt->setAutoDraw(true);
rt->addChild(sprite);
rt->addChild(label);
auto rtSprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
ProgressTimer* progress = ProgressTimer::create(rtSprite);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check out `setAutoDraw` and try that, instead of doing the `begin` and `end` stuff I was trying earlier. That may have been the reason I was getting strange results.

Comment: Cool, begin() and end() should give you the same results (auto draw internally just calls begin/end with visit on its children), but hopefully autodraw works for you.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm having trouble getting it going, but I'm sure that this is the right answer. Do you have a repo somewhere where I can see this stuff in action? Also now you're creating the progress timer with the original sprite, not the rtsprite, haha.

Comment: lol, so much for writing code from scratch in stackoverflow editor :D I'll look for some in-action code, might be the tests project will be best

Comment: I think the issue is that using the texture right away doesn't give the RT time to actually draw. Using the `begin` and `end` funcitons lets it actually draw. The way I was using it was create the progress bar's sprite once, and then redraw the progressbar on the fly. It seems like the RTs are for constant updating or something.

Comment: I added a final complete answer with the Label. You were right about this not being intended though, support is very finicky. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I was able to add the Label to the ProgressTimer no problem this time around. I must have been doing something strange the first time. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently re-approached this problem, and found an actual solution. Turns out  @SteveTranby was right to not use the renderTexture at first.

```
auto lbl = Label::createWithTTF("label string", my_font_name, 25);
lbl->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
auto front_size = my_progress_timer->getContentSize();
lbl->setPosition(Vec2(
    front_size.width/2.0f,
    front_size.height/2.0f
));
lbl->setTextColor(Color4B::BLACK);
my_progress_timer->addChild(lbl);
```

was enough to do what I wanted. I'm not sure why this wasn't working before.